# open function shows a non identical behaviour

Tags: python

while writing open function we can do certain operation on the data . such as read , write etc
i was trying to read a text file using 'with'. but came across a thing which i never noticed before .

This code prints only the third line and second line and leaves the center space empty.

```py
with open(lines, "r") as File1:
    fileContents = File1.read()
    print(fileContents)
    print(File1.read(1))
    print(File1.read(3))
    print(File1.read(5))
    print(File1.read(7))
    print(File1.read(9))
    print(File1.read(11))
    print(File1.closed)
    print(fileContents)
```

while using this:

```
fileContents = File1.read()
print(fileContents)
```

or only this:

```
print(File1.read(1))
print(File1.read(3))
print(File1.read(5))
print(File1.read(7))
print(File1.read(9))
print(File1.read(11))
```

i get the result. but not getting the expected result when merged both.

Comment: Each call to `File1.read()` starts reading from where the previous one finished. `File1.read()` reads until the end of the file, so there's nothing left for the other calls to read.

Comment: The moment you call `File1.read()` your cursor is at the end of the file. If you want to start at the beginning again, you should add `File1.seek(0)` before doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you first use the `read()` method, without any parameters, the entire file is read.
print the `tell()` method before and after using the `read()` operations to better understand this concept.

Here's a simple code

```py
with open(filename) as f: # read mode by default
    print(f.tell()) # Output: 0
    contents = f.read() # Say there are 189 characters
    print(f.tell()) # Output: 189
```

If you would like to restart the read from the 0th character, you can use the `seek()` method and pass in the index, in this case it is `0`.

Further adding to the above code I provided:

```py
    f.seek(0)
    print(f.tell()) # Output 0
```

When you pass parameters to the read as you mentioned with 1, 3, 5, ... You may use the `tell()` method again to understand this.

Further adding to the above code I provided:

```py
    print(f.tell()) # 0
    f.read(1)
    print(f.tell()) # 1
    f.read(3)
    print(f.tell()) # 1+3 so output = 4
```

Hope this answers your question and clears your doubts.